# C# order string

Tags: c#, .net, string

How can I determine which string is before another if ordered alphabetically?

Examples:

```
is "add" before "ask"? true
is "aaaabba" before "aaac"? true
is "xeon" before "alphabet"? false
```

Is there something in .NET that can do this? Or does someone know of a good method to do this? Thanks in advance. I am using C#, but another language is fine for examples, or even pseudocode, or an idea, thanks.

Comment: compareTo on the string should retuen an int which when less than , equal , greater than shows the current string is bwfore , same as or after the string with which it is being compared

Comment: which container/ collection type are you using.  collections have IndexOf statement to check the index.. that will help to identify..

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could use the [Compare](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/84787k22.aspx) static method or [CompareTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.compareto.aspx) instance method:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Compare("add", "ask") < 0);
        Console.WriteLine(string.Compare("aaaabba", "aaac") < 0);
        Console.WriteLine(string.Compare("xeon", "alphabet") < 0);
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
True
True
False
```

Answer (score 4):

Cation at comparing culture-aware strings !

```
  String s1 = "Strasse";
  String s2 = "Straße";

  var res = String.Compare(s1, s2, StringComparison.Ordinal) == 0; // returns false

  CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("de-DE");
  eq = String.Compare(s1, s2, true, ci) == 0; // returns true
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [string.Compare method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.string.compare.aspx)

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Console.WriteLine(
            "is 'add' before 'ask'? {0}", 
            string.Compare("add", "ask") < 0
            );
        Console.WriteLine(
            "is 'aaaabba' before 'aaac'? {0}",
            string.Compare("aaaabba", "aaac") < 0
            );
        Console.WriteLine(
            "is 'xeon' before 'alphabet'? {0}", 
            string.Compare("xeon", "alphabet") < 0
            );

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `StringComparer` class
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparer.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can just use

```
int result = String.Compare(stringa, stringb);
```

If result > 0, then stringa would be before stringb, < 0 stringb before stringa and 0 for when they are the same.

Answer (score 0):

string.Compare is the function you're looking for.

If the result is greater than 0, then the first argument is greater than the second one. If it's lower than 0 then it's the second one. If the function returns 0, then both arguments are equal.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using some container then you can check index value to check this is it index before or not like this:

```
if( Array.IndexOf(strArray, "C") < Array.IndexOf(strArray, "C") ) return true;
```

As you know it is Ordered according to `alphabet` then you can use [String.Compare Method (String, String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/84787k22.aspx)

```
retun  string.Compare(string1, string2) < 0 ? true : false
```

The comparison uses the `current culture` to obtain culture-specific information such as `casing rules and the alphabetic order of individual characters`. For example, a culture could specify that certain combinations of characters be treated as a single character, or uppercase and lowercase characters be compared in a particular way, or that the sorting order of a character depends on the characters that precede or follow it.

When comparing strings, you should call the Compare method, which `requires that you explicitly specify the type of string comparison that the method uses`. For more information, see [Best Practices for Using Strings in the .NET Framework.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465121.aspx#Y1596)